# Read csv converts numeric column to data type string instead of float

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data from 2 files with similar formats using pandas. Both files contain the same column with all numeric values (positive and negative). One file reads the data in as floats and the other file reads the data in as strings. I need to format both columns with this line of code:

```
df['MTMValue'] = df['MTMValue'].apply(lambda x: "${:.2f}".format(x))
```

This works for one of the files, but for the other file it gives me this error.

```
could not convert string to float: '(241507.20)'
```

I am unsure why one file is converting this column to string data type and the other converts it to float data type.

Is there a way to work around this error?

I have parsed through both files and the formatting of each column is exactly the same. I am unsure why this behavior is happening

here is the code for the file that is reading correctly:

```
def clean_cols(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if col not in ['Commodity', 'FixedPriceStrike', 'Quantity', 'MTMValue']:
            for i in range(0, len(df)):
                df.at[i, col] = str.strip(df[col].iloc[i])

    return df

def get_float_prices(df):
    return df

# specify path to file 
file = "Y:\HedgeFundRecon\JAron\JAron.csv"

# specify column headers
header = ['TradeID', 'TradeDate', 'Commodity', 'StartDate', 'ExpiryDate', 'FixedPriceStrike', 'FixedPriceCurr', 'Deal Type', 'Quantity', 'MTMValue']

# read file into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(file, header= None, skiprows=11, names = header)

# create empty dataframe with same column headings
formatted_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)

# loop through dataframe 
for i in range(0, len(df)-1, 2):

    # locate two consecutive rows
    row1 = df.iloc[i]
    row2 = df.iloc[i + 1] if i + 1 < len(df) else None
    
    # check if the third consecutive row is empty
    # if it is empty we need to combine this row as well
    if str.strip(df.iloc[i + 2, 0]) == '': 
        row3 = df.iloc[i + 2] if i + 2 < len(df) else None
    else:
        row3 = None

    # create a dictionary 
    combined_row = {}

    # loop through each column
    # if the column needs to be combined, 
    # get the data from the rows and store it in dictionary 
    for col in df.columns:
        if col in ['Commodity', 'Quantity', 'FixedPriceStrike']:  # Specify the columns to be combined
            if row3 is None:
                combined_row[col] = [row1[col], row2[col] if row2 is not None else None]
            else: 
                combined_row[col] = [row1[col], row2[col] if row2 is not None else None, row3[col]]
        else:
            combined_row[col] = row1[col]

    # append dictionary to dataframe
    formatted_df = formatted_df._append(combined_row, ignore_index=True)

    # add new columns
    formatted_df['Counterparty'] = 'JAron'

    # drop rows that contain NaN values
    formatted_df = formatted_df.dropna(how='any')

# drop columns 
formatted_df = formatted_df.drop('FixedPriceCurr', axis=1)
formatted_df = formatted_df.drop('Deal Type', axis=1)

# clean columns
formatted_df = clean_commodity(formatted_df)
formatted_df = clean_cols(formatted_df)

# format date columns
formatted_df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(formatted_df['StartDate'], format='%d%b%y')
formatted_df['ExpiryDate'] = pd.to_datetime(formatted_df['ExpiryDate'], format='%d%b%y')
formatted_df['TradeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(formatted_df['TradeDate'], format='%d%b%y')

# get deal type
formatted_df = get_deal_type(formatted_df)

# get quantity
formatted_df = get_quantity(formatted_df)

# get fixed price
formatted_df = get_fixed_price(formatted_df)

# reorder columns
formatted_df = formatted_df.iloc[:,[0,1,8,9,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

# groups rows based on StartDate, Commodity, and DealType
formatted_df['Commodity'] = formatted_df['Commodity'].apply(tuple)
groups = formatted_df.groupby(['StartDate', 'Commodity', 'DealType'])

df_list = []
for name, group in groups:
    grouped_df = pd.DataFrame(group)
    grouped_df['TotalFixedCost'] = grouped_df['FixedPriceStrike'] * grouped_df['Quantity']
    grouped_df['FloatPrice'] = -(grouped_df['MTMValue'] - grouped_df['TotalFixedCost']) / grouped_df['Quantity']
    grouped_df['CostPerUnit'] = grouped_df['TotalFixedCost'] / grouped_df['Quantity']
    grouped_df.loc["Total", "Quantity"] = grouped_df['Quantity'].sum()
    grouped_df.loc["Total", "TotalFixedCost"] = grouped_df['TotalFixedCost'].sum()
    grouped_df.loc["Total", "MTMValue"] = grouped_df['MTMValue'].sum()
    grouped_df.loc["Total", "FloatPrice"] = -(grouped_df.loc["Total", "MTMValue"] - grouped_df.loc["Total", "TotalFixedCost"]) / grouped_df.loc["Total", "Quantity"]
    grouped_df.loc["Total", "CostPerUnit"] = grouped_df.loc["Total", "TotalFixedCost"] /  grouped_df.loc["Total", "Quantity"]

    df_list.append(grouped_df)
    #today = str(date.today().strftime('%d%b%Y')) 
    #grouped_df.to_csv(f"Y:\HedgeFundRecon\JAron\Output\JAronOutput-{today}.csv", index=False, mode='a')

# create float price column
for item in df_list:
    for i in range(0, len(item)-1):
       formatted_df.at[item.index[i],'FloatPrice'] = item.loc["Total", "FloatPrice"]

# format currency coulmns 
formatted_df['FixedPriceStrike'] = formatted_df['FixedPriceStrike'].apply(lambda x: "${:.2f}".format(x))
formatted_df['MTMValue'] = formatted_df['MTMValue'].apply(lambda x: "${:.2f}".format(x))
formatted_df['FloatPrice'] = formatted_df['FloatPrice'].apply(lambda x: "${:.2f}".format(x))

# output formatted results to new file
today = str(date.today().strftime('%d%b%Y')) 
formatted_df.to_csv(f"Y:\HedgeFundRecon\JAron\Output\JAronOutput-{today}.csv", index=False)
```

here is the code for the file that is reading incorrectly:

```
def clean_cols(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if col not in ['FloatPrice','FixedPriceStrike', 'Quantity', 'MTMValue']:
            for i in range(0, len(df)):
                df.at[i, col] = str.strip(df[col].iloc[i])

    return df

def get_deal_type(df):
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if df['DealType'].iloc[i] == 'Pay Float':
            df.at[i, 'DealType'] = 'Sell'
        elif df['DealType'].iloc[i] == 'Pay Fixed':
            df.at[i, 'DealType'] = 'Buy'

    return df

# specify path to file 
file = "Y:\HedgeFundRecon\Macquarie_DHR\Macquarie.csv"

# read file into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=36)

#drop unused columns
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Deal Type', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Period End Date', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Outstanding Volume', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Volume Units', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Price Units', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Trade Currency', axis=1)

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    # add new column 
    df['Counterparty'] = 'Macquarie'

    # drop rows that contain NaN values
    df = df.dropna(how='any', axis=0)


# reorder and rename columns
df = df.iloc[:,[1,2,10,5,0,3,4,7,9,6,8]]
df.rename(columns = {'Deal Number':'TradeID'}, inplace = True)
df.rename(columns = {'Deal Date':'TradeDate'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Pay Fixed/Float':'DealType'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Asset':'Commodity'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Period Start Date':'StartDate'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Maturity Date':'ExpiryDate'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Fwd Price':'FixedPriceStrike'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Projected Rate':'FloatPrice'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Total Volume':'Quantity'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Market Reval (USD)*':'MTMValue'}, inplace = True) 

#clean columns
df = clean_cols(df)

# get deal type
df = get_deal_type(df)

# format date columns
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
df['ExpiryDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ExpiryDate'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
df['TradeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TradeDate'], format='%d-%b-%Y')

# format currency coulmns 
df['FixedPriceStrike'] = df['FixedPriceStrike'].apply(lambda x: "${:.2f}".format(x))
df['MTMValue'] = df['MTMValue'].apply(lambda x: "${:.2f}".format(x))
df['FloatPrice'] = df['FloatPrice'].apply(lambda x: "${:.2f}".format(x))


# groups rows based on StartDate, Commodity, and DealType
groups = df.groupby(['StartDate', 'Commodity', 'DealType'])

for name, group in groups:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(group) 
    #today = str(date.today().strftime('%d%b%Y')) 
    #new_df.to_csv(f"Y:\HedgeFundRecon\Macquarie_DHR\Output\MacquarieOutput-{today}.csv", index=False, mode='a')

# output formatted results to new file
today = str(date.today().strftime('%d%b%Y')) 
df.to_csv(f"Y:\HedgeFundRecon\Macquarie_DHR\Output\MacquarieOutput-{today}.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Did you compared encoding and checked for white spaces?

Comment: There is no white spaces, but I am unsure how to compare encoding

Comment: The easiest way is to enforce encoding when reading the csv "df = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-8') and look for errors, you can check the encoding using text editor such as notepad++ or upload the file online. you can also use python chardet library.

Comment: If both files have negative numbers indicated with a `-` sign, then the data must be getting changed during or after reading the csv, so you will need to share that code for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @Nick i updated the question with all my code. I did think it was happening because of my clean_cols function, but I am formatting the data in both instances after that is being called so I am unsure

Comment: There's nothing in that code which changes the value in `MTMValue` (only a column rename to that) before you attempt to format it. So there must be a number in parentheses in the file.

Comment: Note you don't need to put `df['Counterparty'] = 'Macquarie'` and `df = df.dropna(how='any', axis=0)` in a loop

Comment: Also you can put all your column renames in one call with a dict that contains all the renames.

Comment: And `.map("{:.2f}".format)` is likely more efficient that `.apply(lambda x: "${:.2f}".format(x))`

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not both comprised strictly of numbers.

As the diagnostic makes clear, one of them has parentheses characters mixed in with the numeric characters. One could certainly use parentheses to denote a negative number, but it will require some pre-processing to tell pandas about that convention.

Simplest thing to do would be to tell pandas to ignore errors, so such string values get turned into NaN’s, which you might choose to drop.

Comment: so each file does not denote a negative number with parentheses. it is denoted with '-' a minus sign. I stepped through the dataframe and noticed that one file keeps the format from the file with the minus sign, and the other file adds the parentheses to denote a negative. This is why an error is thrown in one file and not the other.